Why $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6n+1)^3}=\frac{1}{6^3}(91\zeta(3)+2\sqrt3\pi^3)$ is just the tip of the iceberg (Part 1)
While trying to solve this post (an identity also mentioned by Ramanujan), I noticed it had two parts of interest. This is the first one.
I. Definitions
Given the Hurwitz zeta function,
$$\zeta(s,a) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(k+a)^s}$$
Define the zeta sums,
$$\zeta_s\big(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\big) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(k+a_1)^s}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(k+a_2)^s} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(k+a_3)^s} +\dots$$
We will focus only on Apery's constant so $s=3$.

II. Levels 3 & 7
For level $3=2\times\color{red}1+1$, only a linear root $\color{blue}{u_1=3}$ is needed,
$$\qquad 6^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(6n+1)^3} = 91\,\zeta(3)+2\sqrt{3}\,\pi^3 = \frac{7}{2}(3^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,u_1}{\sqrt{3}}\pi^3$$
But for level $7=2\times\color{red}3+1$, we may use cubic roots $x_i$,
$$14^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(14n+1)^3}+\frac1{(14n+3)^3}+\frac1{(14n+5)^3}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\, x_1}{\sqrt{7}}\pi^3$$
$$14^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(14n+3)^3}+\frac1{(14n+9)^3}+\frac1{(14n+13)^3}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\, x_2}{\sqrt{7}}\pi^3$$
$$14^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(14n+5)^3}+\frac1{(14n+11)^3}+\frac1{(14n+13)^3}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\, x_3}{\sqrt{7}}\pi^3$$
where the $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ are the three roots of the minimal polynomial of,
$$x = \frac{\sqrt7}{4}\left(\frac{\cos\tfrac{\pi}{14}}{\big(\sin\tfrac{\pi}{14}\big)^3}+\frac{\cos\tfrac{3\pi}{14}}{\big(\sin\tfrac{3\pi}{14}\big)^3}+\frac{\cos\tfrac{5\pi}{14}}{\big(\sin\tfrac{5\pi}{14}\big)^3}\right)$$
namely,
$$x^3 + 56x^2 - 3724x -208936 = 0$$

III. Level 7 & 11
More concisely, using our zeta sum definition in Part I, then for level $7$,
$$\zeta_3\left(\frac1{14},\frac3{14},\frac5{14}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,x_1}{\sqrt{7}}\pi^3$$
$$\zeta_3\left(\frac3{14},\frac9{14},\frac{13}{14}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,x_2}{\sqrt{7}}\pi^3$$
$$\zeta_3\left(\frac5{14},\frac{11}{14},\frac{13}{14}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(7^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,x_3}{\sqrt{7}}\pi^3$$
And for level $11 = 2\times\color{red}5+1$,
$$\zeta_3\left(\frac1{22},\frac3{22},\frac5{22},\frac{7}{22},\frac{9}{22}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(11^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,y_1}{\sqrt{11}}\pi^3$$
$$\zeta_3\left(\frac1{22},\frac3{22},\frac5{22},\frac{13}{22},\frac{15}{22}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(11^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,y_2}{\sqrt{11}}\pi^3$$
$$\zeta_3\left(\frac1{22},\frac3{22},\frac9{22},\frac{15}{22},\frac{17}{22}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(11^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,y_3}{\sqrt{11}}\pi^3$$
$$\zeta_3\left(\frac1{22},\frac5{22},\frac9{22},\frac{15}{22},\frac{19}{22}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(11^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,y_4}{\sqrt{11}}\pi^3$$
$$\zeta_3\left(\frac3{22},\frac5{22},\frac9{22},\frac{15}{22},\frac{21}{22}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(11^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,y_5}{\sqrt{11}}\pi^3$$
where the $y_i$ are the five roots of a quintic solvable in radicals given by the minimal polynomial of,
$$y = \frac{\sqrt{11}}{4}\sum_{k=1}^5 \frac{\cos\frac{(2k-1)}{22}\pi}{\left(\sin\frac{(2k-1)}{22}\pi\right)^3}$$
namely,
$$y^5 - 11(81y^4) + 11^2(1574y^3 + 329990y^2) - 11^3(14764269y - 1462527463) = 0$$

IV. Question
Let us limit to prime levels $p=4n+3 = 3,7,11,19,$ etc. So given,
$$\zeta_3\left(\frac1{22},\frac3{22},\frac5{22},\frac{7}{22},\frac{9}{22}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(11^3-1)\,\zeta(3)+\frac{2\,y_1}{\sqrt{11}}\pi^3$$
or its partner,
$$\zeta_3\left(\frac{13}{22},\frac{15}{22},\frac{17}{22},\frac{19}{22},\frac{21}{22}\right) = \frac{7}{2}(11^3-1)\,\zeta(3) \color{red}-\frac{2\,y_1}{\sqrt{11}}\pi^3$$
how do we derive the four other "conjugates" $\zeta_3\big(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\big)$ using only first principles? (I used an integer relations algorithm.)
In general, for prime $p=4n+3$, the fractions $a_k$ of the conjugates are not random. So how do we derive them? (P.S. The sequel to this post is here.)

Fascinating as usual !

@ClaudeLeibovici Thank you, Claude. Hopefully someone can shed light to this post and its sequel.

(Part of the answer. Perhaps someone can complete it.) We start with the well-known formula for Apery's constant,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(2n+1)^3} = \frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)\tag{eq.1}$$
and express it as,
$$\zeta(3,\tfrac{1}{2p})+\zeta(3,\tfrac{3}{2p}) + \dots + \zeta(3,\tfrac{2p-1}{2p})= \frac{7}{8}(2p)^3\,\zeta(3)\tag{eq.2}$$
Then using the general identity,
$$\zeta(3,a_k)-\zeta(3,1-a_k)=\frac{\cos (a_k\pi)}{\sin^3 (a_k\pi)}\,\pi^3\tag{eq.3}$$
repeatedly add (eq.3) to (eq.2) for carefully chosen rational $a_k$ to eliminate $k$ terms from (eq.2). We then get the form,
$$\zeta(3,a_1)+\zeta(3,a_2) + \zeta(3,a_3) + \dots = \zeta_3(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots) = \frac{7}{2}(p^3-1)\zeta(3)+ \frac{2\beta}{\sqrt{p}}\pi^3$$
where $\beta$ is an algebraic number (since it is a sum of trigonometric functions). The trick then is to find the right set of $a_k$ so that $\beta$ has nice properties, such as being an integer as discussed in another post.

To address the question in this post, for $p=11$, it turns out we can use modular arithmetic,

S_n = Sort[Table[Mod[(2k - 1)^n, 22], {k, 1, 5}]]

for odd powers $n$ (in Mathematica syntax). Thus,
$$S_1 = (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)\\ S_3 = (1, 3, 5, 13, 15)\\ S_7 = (1, 3, 9, 15, 17)\\ S_9 = (1, 5, 9, 15, 19)$$
which yield the correct $a_k$ numerators of 4 of the 5 functions $\zeta_3\big(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\big)$ in the question above. But the answer is incomplete since it does not give the 5th function. Also, for $p\neq11$, it does not yield the "conjugates", so a more comprehensive answer is desired. However, this modular arithmetic is useful when $\beta$ is an integer as seen later in the second post.
